# How to Download File From Website that Generated File id to download?

Tags: vb.net

I m using web browser control to download file where URL generate file dynamically.
First, I have to upload pdf file then website converts the pdf file into excel after conversion process website generates URL contains file id after requesting that URL website create file dynamically and then save dialog comes. How to handle such type of URL?

Example :
I have uploaded File name: 123.pdf

After conversion process webiste generates Url: https:www.123.com/api/download/562362

Then,

When I click on that Url save dialog comes and downloaded file name will be 123.xlsx

How to download the file without showing save dialog? (I m not able to download programmatically.)

[Sample_Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M68gs.png)

Comment: You might find this helpful:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.filedownload?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Also:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa753618%28v%3dvs.85%29

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WebClient object to download the file from the website.

You just create a new Webclient and then you use the DonwloadFile function to download it to your computer.

Check this link out for more information : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of this API call?

Comment: @MaximGoncharuk                                                                                                
    `Imports System.Net                                                                                            
     Dim client as new WebClient                                                                                                                                                                                          
     client.DownloadFile("link to download website","filename.pdf")`